# How to get all data from one table and replace the value from another table if exist?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have two tables.

Table 1

```
| id         | name        | description  |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| 1          | abc         |     qqq
| 2          | efg         |     qqq
| 3          | hij         |     wqq
| 4          | klm         |     c
| 5          | nop         |     de
| 6          | qrs         |     aa
```

Table 2

```
| id         | quantity    |
|:-----------|------------:|
| 1          | 10          | 
| 2          | 21          |
```

I would like to show all of the records from table 1 and then get the quantity from table 2. If the id in table 1 exist in table 2 then then quantity value will be as listed in table 2 else i will set 0 for the id where not found in table 2.

I tried this

```
DB::table('table1')
->leftJoin('table2', function($join) use($option){
$join->where('option', $option)
->on('table1.id', '=', 'table2.id');
})
->select(table1.*','table2.*')
->get();
```

It returns all the item from table1 but it is only get the id existed in table2 others will return null.

How can i do to get expected result?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT tab1.*, ifnull(tab2.quantity, 0) AS qty
FROM tab1
LEFT JOIN tab2 ON tab1.id = tab2.id
```

Comment: ok, thanks. I shouldn't select all from table 2, i think everything is working fine now.